# How to deploy Application in JBOSS?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, java-ee-7

Successfully I installed `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final` in windows 7 using `StackoverFlow` help. I have a Application name as HellowWorld . Inside HellowWorld  Application folder I have `WEB-INF`sub folder and `Hellow.jsp` file.

I want to test,whether Application is working or not.for this I tried in following way

I placed my entire folder under `<jboss-Home>//standalone//deployments`,started my server and log in but I didn't seen any files in my console page.

How will I deploy App?

Thanks

Comment: see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Application+deployment?_sscc=t

Answer (score 2):

Try to make a war file of your app

```
jar -cvf app1.war *
```

and deploy

Comment: I created war file name as webMathematica.war,I deployed through console page.I tried to open my application in browser using the following url `Http://localhost:8080/webMathematica`.but it showing 404 error.I think URL problem. how can I test my App.

Comment: I tried with same URL what you suggested me.but it's not working.is there any way to open from console page?

Comment: If JBoss deployed your app it had to print ..registering webcontext: /ebMathematica ... Deployed ebMathematica.war on console

Comment: I tried it on my JBoss 1.1.1 it works OK. Did you see ...Deployed ebMathematica.war.. on JBoss console?